# SQLite SELECT with JOIN and GROUP?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to add a column based on the result of the following string:

```
SELECT product_code AS "Product Code", SUM(quantity) AS "Quantity" 
FROM receipts_items
GROUP BY product_code
ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC
```

this string gives me a Product Code and the quantity sold. What I need to add is, based on the product code, the description of that product code.

product_code and descriptions column are in the same table "products"
quantity is in another table "receipts_items"

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to `JOIN` the two tables on `product_code`.

You really ought to do a `LEFT JOIN` to catch products with no associated receipt items, then put a `CASE` statement in your `SUM` to reduce `NULL` values to 0.

```
SELECT p.product_code AS "Product Code",
    p.description AS "Description", 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ri.quantity IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ri.quantity END) AS "Quantity" 
FROM products AS p
    LEFT JOIN receipts_items AS ri ON ri.product_code = p.product_code
GROUP BY p.product_code
ORDER BY SUM(ri.quantity) DESC
```

Comment: quick question: I did take the quantity sold and multiplied by price of each item. I get the result in a new column but with more than one decimal. any idea on how to get MAX 2 decimals? Thank you again!

Comment: Simply use `ROUND(value, 2)`

Comment: it works! thanks!!! only thing is that if value is 74 it will not add two zeros so it can be: 74.00

Comment: You can just use [`IFNULL`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) instead of the `CASE` expression.

Comment: @CL - a CASE statement is the ANSI compliant way of doing an IFNULL.  It will work with any ANSI-compliant DBMS.